Weird marks on drywall
I noticed these weird lines? Or Cracks in my drywall ceiling today. I’m not sure what’s causing it. We did just have our apartment building power washed today.
TIA

it appers to be leaking

Those are typical cracks in old paint that was applied to a surface without good prep. Sometimes the paint cracks soon after application, sometimes it cracks days, months, or years afterwards. It usually goes along with big humidity changes, for example when all of the windows are closed and the humidity in the houses raises. Since you had your house washed, you probably had the windows closed and the trapped humidity might have done it.

I just want to mention that they are softer than the existing drywall. I’m not sure if it’s a result of water damage and if it is, do I have to worry about the ceiling caving in?

For the drywall to cave in, you need lots of water, as in water pouring down. This does not seem to be the case

Thank you for your insights. I’m still going to let my landlord know regardless, in the event it is because of a leak
